# Drawing cross section lines within a polygon

Tags: c++, geometry

I currently have a list of polygons made up of several points. The first of these is the outer polygon of the cross section and the others in shapes inside the first polygon.

I'm trying to think of a way to draw cross section lines inside the outer polygon (and not inside the inner polygons) but I'm struggling to think of a way to do this. Does anyone have any suggestions?

I'm writing in C++ using an API that lets me draw lines between points easily enough. The drawing I'm creating is in 3D, which I'm guessing will make things a bit easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't mention your OS or your development environment, so it's not clear that there may be other solutions. However, going back to basics, perhaps consider the [Painter's Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Painter's_algorithm) and don't worry about clipping or cropping your content based on existing content - just do something like this:

1. Draw cross section lines on the whole image.
2. Draw the inverse of the outer polygon with a black fill (that will remove the cross section lines that are outside the outer polygon.
3. Draw the inner shapes with a black fill (that will remove the cross sections lines that are inside the inner polygons).

The Wiki page shows this example:

[image: painters]

If you're using Windows and are ok to use Direct2D (or Direct3D), there are much easier ways to do this by drawing shapes with a customised brush for filling.

Comment: Hmm, that's an interesting suggestion. It might be quite tricky to do with a larger scale drawing though (with no background either). I'll read a bit more into it though, see if I can make it work (I'm on Windows but I'm not using Direct2D/3D, unfortunately).

Comment: @Incredidave Ok, it sort of underlies the mechanics of 3D drawing where there is a concept of a depth buffer and each pixel (technically *fragment*) is tested before drawing to check that it is "in front of" the existing content. You may be reinventing the wheel here though.

Comment: So while I don't think this will work in my particular situation it is a correct answer to the question as I asked it. I'll mark you right to help out anyone in the future who has this issue.